# Can I use both nuxt generate and file structure to build dynamic routes?

Tags: nuxt.js, dynamic-routing, nuxtjs2

Using Nuxt 2 (2.15), I have dynamic pages generating e.g. example.com/page1, example.com/page2 etc. The name of the file generating these pages is `_page.vue`.

This has worked fine until a recent change, where I implemented generate routes in `nuxt.config.js`, like so:

```
generate: {
    routes: [
      '/fanpages/page1',
      '/fanpages/page2', etc...
    ]
  }
```

Now the new routes work, but the original dynamic pages do not work. How can I ensure both types of dynamic page generation work?

Alternatively, there may be a better solution? The reason for the above setup is that the existing set of dynamic routes is unknown and generated by a CMS, and the new set is known dynamic routes that require SEO properties built into the HTML when the project is built.